# combineLatest operator alternative

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I crafted this solution as an alternative to `combineLatest` operator
in another words want to switch my original stream into another one but still have access to value from original stream

`switchMap(sourceValue => combineLatest([of(sourceValue), anotherObservable]))`

Could you all help me find easier/more elegant solution than this one?

Comment: `combineLatest` creation method is not deprecated. Only `combineLatest` operator is deprecated.

Comment: yes sorry @martin i edited my post. hope my question is more clear now

Comment: What is that a simple use of combineLatest does not provide you? In other words, why `combineLatest(observableEmittingSourceValue, anotherObservable)` does not work for you? The use of `combineLatest` creation function would return an Observable which emits an array of 2 values coming from the 2 Observables, so that the value of the original stream would be always the first value in the array.

Answer (score 2):

So, whenever your original observable emits a sourceValue, you want to emit pairs [sourceValue, otherValue] where otherValue comes from another observable (to be resubscribed everytime the original sourceValue changes), right ?

if so, the original code should be equivalent to the somewhat more self-explanatory (and more efficient):

`switchMap(sourceValue => anotherObservable.pipe(map( otherValue => [sourceValue, otherValue] )) )`

Comment: I want to switch my original stream into another one but still have access to value from original stream.

Comment: Ok, so this should work, as long as you're ok with the resulting sorceValue lifetime and identity (if it has non primitive type, of course); you may also want to replace the array pair with an actual object, maybe exploiting typescript to gain better type checking downstream... Ymmv